# Is my code sloppy/bad?

Tags: java

Was just wondering if I was using nested if statements to much. I've been looking around and it seems that people try to not use them. Also does the code look messy in any way? Anyways here it is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

private String user_input = "";
private int max_score = 6;
private int sum;

private void check_scores(String scores){
    user_input = scores;
    String[] temp;

    // Check if user_input is valid
    // ^ Match with beginning of line | [0-9] Allow 0-9 | , Allow comma | + Match one or more | $ Match End of line
    if (user_input.matches("^[0-9,]+$")) {

        // Check if string starts with an ,
        if(user_input.charAt(0) == ',') {
            // If it does parse and substring to remove them
            // otherwise the following regex leaves one behind
            int i = 0;
            while (!Character.isDigit(user_input.charAt(i))) i++;
            int j = user_input.length();
            user_input = user_input.substring(i,j);
        }

        // (.) Match any character) | \1 If it is followed by itself | + Match one or more | $1 replace by the first captured char.
        user_input = user_input.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");

        System.out.println(user_input);

        // Split at the ',' and put each number in it's own cell in the array
        temp = user_input.split(",");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));

        // Check if temp is equal to max_scores
        if (temp.length == max_score){
            int[] ui_array = new int[temp.length];

            // Parse String[] into int[]
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
                try {
                    ui_array[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {}; // If triple checking isn't enough...
            }
            System.out.println("temp array(String): " + Arrays.toString(temp));
            System.out.println("ui_array(int): " + Arrays.toString(ui_array));

            // Add up all elements in ui_array
            for (int j = 0 ; j < ui_array.length; j++) {
                sum += ui_array[j];
            }
            System.out.println("Scores sum:" + sum + " Number of scores:" + ui_array.length + " Number of ends:" + ui_array.length/6);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You have " + temp.length + " scores. Acceptable amount is " + max_score);
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input. (Only #'s and ,'s allowed)");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.check_scores("1,M,7,10,,4,8,");
    main.check_scores("1,6,7,10,,4,8,,,,,,,1,2,6,10,2,10");
    main.check_scores(",,,,,,,1,2,6,10,2,10");
    main.check_scores("10,2,1,5,7,1");
    main.check_scores("6,2, ,,5,6,1");
    }
}
```

I have just been wondering for a while what people think about how I go about doing things.

Comment: This kind of question is better suited for [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: consider refactoring that method.

Comment: Why rename `scores`? If you want it called `user_input` just rename the parameter. Also you should do a new line after your while condition. You also should rename temp to something meaningful; The only time I use temp is if it's only going to be used for something trivial in only a few lines, but you're using it a lot so it deserves a descriptive name. I downvoted this question because like irrelephant said, this is what CodeReview Stack Exchange is for.

Comment: @irrelephant I'm sorry, I did not know that that existed. Should I move it over there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things I would note:

1. Personally, I think something like

   public void method()
      {

   }

Is much more readable than

```
public void method() {

}
```

Particularly when you have methods that contain other structures. I'm sure some may not mind either, but I've never heard of someone saying the first isn't readable, while plenty have complained about the second. Sorry about the first one not being formatted correctly, but SO would not allow it.. it seems the site admins disagree with me on this one.

2. It is a standard to name variables such as `someVariableName` rather than `some_variable_name`. The first word should be lower case, all others capital, and they should be contiguous. The same is true for methods.
3. In your `check_scores(String)` method you have `user_input = scores;`, yet with your implementation there is no need for a global variable or to assign the passed variable elsewhere, so this is a waste of memory. Actually, since none of your class variables are used outside of the scope of this method, you should probably declare all of them inside the method.
4. I understand that this is a trivial example, but to go with the idea of object oriented programming, your `Main` class should probably be in a separate file and be run by creating an object in your main method in a driver class instead.

Also, as you mentioned, nesting several statements, when not necessary, can be sloppy since it will quickly become hard to read and follow.